# IEEEtran Author block

Tags: templates, ieeetran, journal-publishing

I have used several times the following authorblock. But now it does not work and I do not know what I have changed.

Thank you in advance,
Ignacio

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\fi
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{Conference title.}
\author{
\authorblockN{Author 1 {1}, Author 2 {2}.}
\authorblockA{\emph{email1@any.com  email2@any.com}}
\vspace{0.05in}
\authorblockA{{1} University 1.}
\authorblockA{{2} University 2.}
\vspace{0.05in}
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 Bla
\end{abstract}
{\smallskip \IEEEkeywords words}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}

Bla

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

You have modified the ref to the author an delete the `IEEE`:

```
\documentclass[conference,a4paper]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\else
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\fi
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\title{Conference title.}
\author{
\IEEEauthorblockN{Author 1\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}, Author 2\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}}
%\vspace{0.05in}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{1}University 1. \emph{email1@any.com}}
\IEEEauthorblockA{\IEEEauthorrefmark{2}University 2. \emph{email2@any.com}}
%\vspace{0.05in}
}
\maketitle
\begin{abstract}
 Bla
\end{abstract}
{\smallskip \IEEEkeywords words}
\IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle
\section{Introduction}

Bla

\end{document}
```

output:

[image]